# Using REST API to Upsert a Child record onto a Parent record using the Parent's external ID

Tags: apex, lightning, rest-api, lightning-experience, rest

**Error**

```
Lead: id value of incorrect type: EMAIL_HERE
```

**Code**

```
$body = [
       'Name' => 'Survey',
       'Lead__r:MySQL_Email__c' => 'EMAIL_HERE'
   ];
    $result = Forrest::sobjects('Survey_Data_Object__c/External_Id__c/' . SURVEY_ID,[
        'method' => 'patch',
        'body'   => $body]);
```

This doesn't work for some reason. I have also tried the following in `body`:

1. Lead__c
2. MySQL_Email__c

I have also tried this but got an error.

```
'Lead__r' => '{MySQL_Email__c: \'EMAIL_HERE\'},'
```

**Error**
    The value provided for foreign key reference Lead__r is not a nested SObject

Comment: The latter should work as long as `MySQL_Email__c` is an External Id field.

Comment: MySQL_Email__c is an External ID field on Lead, not Survey Data Object. Errors though